# Ruby cannot load such file -- dm--adapter (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying t configure the Salesforce Vulnreport tool, and everytime I run the SEED.rb I get the following error:

```
Setting up the PostgreSQL database...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- dm--adapter (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/dm-core.rb:230:in `setup'
from /root/Documents/Resources/Applications/vulnreport/models/init.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from ./SEED.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

I have checked the Gemfile and 'dm-postgres-adapter' is included and installed. I have no idea why I am getting this error, and though I found others attempting to install this with the same issue, I found no fixes. I am not proficient enough with Ruby to really know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Also I hope this I posted this in an OK place.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the contents of `SEED.rb`? It looks like you've got two hyphens in `dm--adapter` and you only need to have one.

Comment: Hello, the app is by salesforce and under the BSD 3-clause license. Their seed file can be found on the git page https://github.com/salesforce/vulnreport/blob/master/SEED.rb

Comment: Have you installed that entire repository? That file has a `require` statement that refers to a directory and file that are in that repo.

Comment: Ya I cloned the entire repo

Comment: I am not sure if this is an issue with my setup, or their app as I am not the only one to have this problem. I have all the dependencies (seemingly)

Comment: My last suggestion would be to change line 20 in the repo to `require_relative` instead of `require`. It could be something with your ruby path.

Comment: Forgive me, but what do you mean by 'line 20 in the repo?'

Comment: Do you mean in the SEED.rb?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. In `SEED.rb`.

Comment: No problem. Tried it, that didnt do it. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 1):

I realized while looking through my repo that my .env file had a small error in the 'export DATABASE_URL' component which was causing the issue. I was able to fix it by adjusting the incorrect password I had (1 character was off). However, the error message is not very clear. I feel it could have more easily pointed to an authentication failure to the database being the issue.